# react-scripts: command not found exit code 127

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

Both npm and yarn started having this problem after updating macOs.
All the yarn/npm react-scripts(start, build, test), show `exit code 127` error and `react-scripts: command not found.`
This problem is in all of my react projects.

Here's the yarn command line:

```
ianstidsen@Ians-MacBook-Air typescript-test % yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ../../../../../package.json: No license field
$ react-scripts start
/bin/sh: react-scripts: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
ianstidsen@Ians-MacBook-Air typescript-test %
```

Here's the npm command line:

```
ianstidsen@Ians-MacBook-Air test % npm start

> test@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: command not found
ianstidsen@Ians-MacBook-Air test %
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

What i have tried:

1. remove `node_modules` then run `yarn` or `npm install`
2. remove both `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`/`package-lock.json` and run `yarn` or `npm install`
3. `yarn` or `npm install react-scripts`
4. delete the entire project and reinstall using yarn or npm

None of the above worked.